# Is it possible to combine react code to angular code?And is it good idea to do so?

Tags: angular, reactjs

If I have a react code from another project that I want to integrate with my angular 9 project. Is it possible to do so? If its possible, is it still a good idea or would it be better if I rewrite the code into angular?

I haven't go deep into details, but I looked at another thread that it's possible to do so by adding wrapper or directive in the components. What are the benefit to do this? Does it take less effort than re-writing the code?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to do so?

You can render React element to any DOM element.

See [`ReactDOM.render()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#render)

> Render a React element into the DOM in the supplied container and return a reference to the component (or returns null for stateless components).

---

> If its possible, is it still a good idea or would it be better if I rewrite the code into angular?

It is opinioned based question, it is up to you to decide. Think about time consumption and maintenance.